# How to publish an HTML email message on a web page?

Tags: html, dom

I want to publish an email message on my website. The email message source looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>My newsletter</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            p{
                margin:10px 0;
                padding:0;
            }
            table{
                border-collapse:collapse;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
        <center>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <!-- etc, you know what HTML email looks like in 2020... -->
            </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've already tried copying/pasting the email source into an `<iframe>` using its `srcdoc` argument, like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to my website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Have a look at the following email:</h1>

<iframe srcdoc='
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>My newsletter</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            p{
                margin:10px 0;
                padding:0;
            }
            table{
                border-collapse:collapse;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
        <center>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <!-- etc, you know what HTML email looks like in 2020... -->
            </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
'/>

    </body>
</html>
```

This kinda works, but it adds unnecessary scrollbars. I'd prefer the email message was rendered as if it were a regular `<div>`, instead of in its own viewport. Is there a way to include the `<html>` node of my email into my base `HTML` document, while preserving the inner document's layout as much as possible?

Comment: If you have class formatting in the 'injected' email that you put in a div, then the class in the email will affect your page.  This is why iframes are generally used.  You can hide the scroll bars on an iframe.

Comment: I realize that. Still, how would I include the email in a div instead of an iframe?

Comment: You can use "custom element" to build an isolated DOM including styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's me again, posting my own answer inspired by this comment of [@Mosh Feu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/863110/mosh-feu):

> You can use "custom element" to build an isolated DOM including styles.

This answer utilizes [Web Components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Components) to solve the problem of how include an HTML document (in my case an email message) *inside* another HTML document (my website).

First, I placed a `<my-email-message>` tag at the position I wanted my email message to appear. Second, I included the raw source of the email message inside a `<template>` tag, which prevents the web browser from actually rendering it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to my website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Have a look at the following email:</h1>
        <my-email-message />

<template id="raw-email-message">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<!--------------8<------------->
</html>
</template>

    </body>
</html>
```

Then I used the following javascript to attach the email message as a [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) to the custom `<my-email-message>` element (thereby preventing the `<style>` tags inside the email message to inadvertently influence the overall styling of my website):

```
customElements.define('raw-email-message',
                      class extends HTMLElement {
                          constructor() {
                              super();
                              const template = document
                                  .getElementById('email-message')
                                  .content;
                              const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
                                                     .appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));
                          }
                      });
```

The end result is a pretty accurate representation of the email as it appeared in my inbox, displayed on a web page without messing up its layout. I'm still not sure whether this is the correct approach and what the security implications are, however.